# Div vertical scrollbar show

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how its possible to permanently show the vertical bar of a div (greyed out if there is no scrolling) similar to our regular bars. Basically I am trying to place an entire website in a div (like gmail/facebook), so if the page is not long enough the whole page shifts because of the lack of the vertical scroll bar.

I need a solution to this problem. I tried overflow-y:scroll. But it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

What browser are you testing in?

What DOCType have you set?

How exactly are you declaring your CSS?

Are you sure you haven't missed a `;` before/after the `overflow-y: scroll`?

I've just tested the following in IE7 and Firefox and it works fine

```html
<!-- Scroll bar present but disabled when less content -->
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  test
</div>

<!-- Scroll bar present and enabled when more contents -->        
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
  test<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Also tested in IE7 and FireFox, and just <div style="overflow-y:scrol">Hello</div> works.

Comment: this is the style sheet i am using:
#main_container {
 width:100%;
 background-color:#eeeeee; 
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
}

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: oh its working now... thanks.. i bychance placed a style tag saying overflow:auto in the div, which overwrote my external css...

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried `overflow-y:auto` ? It is not exactly what you want, as the scrollbar will appear only when needed.

Answer (score 31):

**Always :** If you always want vertical scrollbar, use `overflow-y: scroll;`

[jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/xEy9E/275/)

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
......
</div>
```

**When needed**: If you only want vertical scrollbar when needed, use  `overflow-y: auto;` (You need to specify a height in this case)

[jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/xEy9E/273/)

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height:150px; ">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In reactjs...

```js
<div className='p-4 mb-4' style={{overflowY:'scroll',height:'350px'}}>
    {msgx.map((m,index)=>{
        return(
            <Items m={m} key={index} i={index}/>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.