# How to make a scrollbar placeholder

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, placeholder

My problem is that the browser windows vertical scrollbar that is removed by for example `overflow:hidden;` will make the page jump, when it reappears later. I use jQuery to remove the scroll option from the visitor, while a script is running and scrolling the page to a specific point, and then to make it reappear again afterwards.

Can I make a placeholder for the scrollbar, when it is not present, so it won't *jump* back?

Or is it possible to "disable" it and have it "greyed out"?

I cannot find any solutions by searching. I have found something similar here: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838545/div-vertical-scrollbar-show) where the scrollbar is always there. But the difference is that the scrollbar must remain disabled, even if the page is longer than the window. It must only be "turned on" again through another script that I control.

Is this in any way possible?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

Time for a status update.

I had some problems with the star cloud background image, which was set on the `body` tag.
When the jQuery script (from cwolves answer) added the padding to the `html` tag and therefore should push all elements on the page to the left, the background image still didn't behave right.

Well, I found out that the `body` element doesn't react like any `div` element. It is not just a "block" inside the `html` tag like any other block element. It has its own behaviors and apparently can't be tricked with in the same way. Therefore the background image was impossible to touch, while it was on `body`.
But it took me some time to realize...

The end solution to this is so flipping stupidly simple that I was almost in tears when finding out, thinking of the endless (I might exaggerate a little) hours of investigating the `body`.
I simply wrapped everything in a `<div id="body">` and gave this the background image instead. Suddenly everything fell into place.

From:

```
<body>
...
</body>
```

And

```
body {background-image: url(...);}
```

To:

```
<body>
<div id="body">
...
</div>
</body>
```

And:

```
#body {background-image: url(...);}
```

And a little bit wiser about the `body`.

No "jumping" anymore. Delicious.

The effect is now fully running and you almost doesn't notice a change with the scroll bar and every detail fits. Cwolve's script is perfect and does the exact calculation:

```
function getScrollBarWidth(){
    var div = $('<div><div>' + new Array(100).join('content<br />') + '</div></div>'),
       div2 = div.find('div'),
       body = $(document.body);

    div.css({ overflow : 'hidden', width: 100, height: 100, position : 'absolute', left : -1000, top : -1000 });
    body.append(div);

    var width1 = div2.width();
    div.css({ overflow : 'auto' });
    var width2 = div2.width();

    div.remove();

    return width1 - width2;
}
```

The `getScrollBarWidth()` will contain exactly the width of the scroll bar no matter the browser, and I can use it to add and remove paddings as I want to:

```
    var sWidth = getScrollBarWidth();

    $("body").css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
    $("html").css({'padding-right': sWidth});
    
    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({
        
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 170
            
    }, 2000, 'swing', function(){

        $("body").css({'overflow': 'auto'});
        $("html").css({'padding-right': 0});

    });
```

Thanks very much. This was a nice one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

- Determine the width of the scrollbar in the current browser
- Set a content div to `padding-right: scrollbar-width`
- Hide scroll on parent

and after the animation:

- Remove padding-right on content
- show scroll on parent

I made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/ezLfU/1/

Comment: Yes, that's a solution, if no direct scroll bar manipulation is possible. But it will depend on the browser and is a laborious work.

Comment: How is is laborious?  I gave you a demo that calculates the scroll-bar width :)  The actual implementation requires you to add the function I made and a whopping 3 lines of code, which are also in the demo (just change the selectors).

Comment: Well, you will have to find the exact scrollbar width for each browser type and implement some kind of browser checking. And still it won't be a safe solution. But it is a part of the way, and a possible solution, so thanks for the answer.

Comment: I gave you code to find the exact scrollbar width...  There is no extra check needed and it's completely safe.  You can ___literally___ drop the code I gave you in and substitute my selectors for `body` and `screen`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for misunderstanding your code. It's actually brilliant. I do though have some trouble in making it work with the `<html>`and `<body>` elements as the wrapper and contentholder, but I suspect it to be something about the `<body>` not acting like any other element. Thank you, I will use your answer to solve my problem.

Comment: Looks good :)  The only thing is that since you're putting the `padding-right` on the HTML, there is a gap between the trees and the rest of the background on the right.  I think if you do that on `#screen`, that issue will go away

Comment: Finally finished! See the update. And thank you for this great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at your site and thought of an alternative approach. If you're hiding the scrollbar with overflow:hidden, you could also reimplement scrolling as well.

Attach events to page up/page down/home/end/arrow up/arrow down, mouse wheel up/mouse wheel down, and then do

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 15)
```

The code above is obviously bad and just an example, but possibly something you may like to try.

Comment: Okay, this is a solution that will work across browsers. It is though quite convoluted instead of just greying out the scroll bar. But that seems not to be possible anyway.

Comment: Right. Usually the browser's not going to let you mess too much with the scrollbar. You're looking to do something convoluted with your site, so you're probably going to get a solution that's more convoluted than elegant.

Answer (score 1):

How about making your content a few pixels less wide than the container and toggling the overflow-y attribute?

Scrollbars can have different widths on different browsers/OSes. If you are not going to calculate the width of the scrollbar you best take it wide enough so it works on all browsers.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3f4Bd/6/)

Comment: That requires knowing exactly how wide the container is and observing the window `resize` event and updating on change.  Plus, your `20px` difference isn't safe since scrollbars can be wider than that.

Comment: Well, this is interesting! But won't I have a problem when trying to set a width of 20 px less than the window? At the site I'm not setting any specific widths for the page element boxes, but only variable widths to make them center aligned. Then they will still jump, as I see it?

Comment: @cwolves true, it depends on the complexity you are willing to put on your page. It is always a trade-off. I thought your solution was over-engineered so I put an alternative with a small trade-off in functionality but a gain in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ to give you some control over the scrollbar and work from that.

Answer (score -1):

Displaying a disabled scrollbar is as simple as setting overflow:scroll;

Vertical only would be `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: No no, this will not give a disabled scrollbar when the page is longer than the screen. Then it starts "working" which I am trying to prevent. It has to be disabled or removed and replaced with a placeholder.

Comment: Ah no I don't believe that is possible with javascript, you'd need a browser plugin to manipulate the browser elements. I thought you just wanted your page to not "jump" when the scroll bar was present. One thing you can do is style your scroll bar to match your page, but unfortunately it only works in IE (Example: http://www.steve-terada.com)