# scrollbar of div not correctly shown (displaced)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

[image]
as shown in the picture the scrollbar is displaced , don't know why.. the content div has the height from the bottom of the navigation bar to the end of the browsers window.

here's the shortened code:

```
<div id="bar">
   <-- BarContent -->
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

css:

```
#containerContent .center .content
{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 1px;
}
```

the height of my div is set with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').height($('#containerContent').height() - $('#bar').height());
}
```

i know:
* it's not the problem of the resize with jquery (tested it with the right heights in css)
* the div is taking all space which is needed

anyone has an idea or solution to make my scrollbar shown correctly?

thanks

### UPDATE

This solution works [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589909/how-to-make-a-scrollbar-placeholder?rq=1) , thanks to Jeremy Voges.

but is there any possibility to fit the scrollbar height in IE? firefox safari etc works

[image]